# Calling a constructor is possible or not?

Tags: c#, .net

I have two classes with same namespace. I want to call the constructor of one class inside of a function which is in another class. Is this possible?

Comment: Have you had a problem doing this? If so, could you show us the code where you have tried this?

Comment: What do you mean about call constructor? Does it include allocation memory for that class? Or just call the constructor on some allocated memory?

Comment: @Thomson: you can't "call a constructor on memory" in C#.

Comment: You don't call the constructor directly. It's called whenever you instantiate an object of that class. What exactly are you trying to achieve? Maybe we can help you with that.

Answer (score 2):

Simply using the **`new`** keyword calls the constructor for the class.

if you want to construct object of another class then simply do this (anywhere.. even in your function):

```
Class2 obj  = new Class2();
```

that's all.

---

Just remember the constructor should have a **public** access.

like:

```
class  Class2 
{
    public Class2()
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If they are in the same namespace, then `new OneClass()` is all you need.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  Why wouldn't it be possible?

Although I'd go with the terminology "construct" over "call constructor".

Answer (score 0):

Yes of course! When you create a new instance of the class, its constructor is invoked (assuming it is a public non-static constructor). You can read more about constructors here - 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k9x6w0hc(VS.80).aspx